# SharePoint Visual studio project Debug issue

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am not able to debug the Sharepoint project in Visual studio solution even after attaching W3workerprocess. please help me on this.

I cheked project properties, website URL is also correct. but still i am not able to debug the solution

Comment: You want to debug a 404 page that is shown?

Comment: normal application page , created using Visual studio and deployed into sharepoint web application. i want to debug this page. normallym if i attach w3 worker process, i was able to debug the solution. But in the current solution,even after attaching the process, i ma not able to debug the code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made any changes that's not deployed/copied to GAC/BIN? If not, copy to GAC/BIN using CKSDev (VS tool) and then do a IIS reset (I think that CKSDev handles this also). Then refresh your page and then attach the process again. Also there's often multiple w3wp.exe you can attach to. I usually select all those.